# Simple proof of $\operatorname{Curl} F = 0$ then F is conservative

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vectors, vector-analysis, curl

Apparently this is just a simple proof with prerequisites for the domain to be a star-like domain.

See picture below for proof:

[image]

I don't however understand why

$\operatorname{Curl} F = 0$ means that we could replace:

$(\frac{\partial}{\partial \xi})F_{2}(\xi,\eta,\zeta) $

with

$(\frac{\partial}{\partial \eta})F_{1}(\xi,\eta,\zeta) $

and

$(\frac{\partial}{\partial \xi})F_{3}(\xi,\eta,\zeta) $

with

$(\frac{\partial}{\partial \eta})F_{1}(\xi,\eta,\zeta) $

Comment: Did you compute the curl of $F$?

Comment: @JasonDeVito I tried with little success. I think i'm interpeting $F(r(t))$ wrong. Is:  $F(r(t))=F_{1}(xt,yt,zt)i+F_{2}(xt,yt,zt)j+F_{3}(xt,yt,zt)k$ a correct interperatation of the vector $F(r(t))$?

Comment: Yes, $F(r(t))$ is as you write (keeping in mind that $(x,y,z)$ is a constant for purposes of this problem).  However, to compute curl, you should be thinking of $F$  as being $F_1(\xi, \eta, \zeta) i + F_2(\xi, \eta, \zeta) j + F_3(\xi, \eta, \zeta) k$  Then, for example, the coefficient of $i$ in the curl of $F$ is $\frac{\partial}{\partial \eta} F_3 - \frac{\partial}{\partial \zeta} F_2$.  Since the curl is zero, $\frac{\partial}{\partial \eta} F_3 = \frac{\partial}{\partial \zeta} F_2$.